# The Keycloak EntityManager can't mapping any model

Tags: java, hibernate, keycloak, hibernate-mapping, entitymanager

Keyсloak version 14.0

I have store some custom tables in The Keycloak postgres database, my entity:

```
public class StoreTestModel {

    public StoreTestModel() {
    }

    public StoreTestModel(Integer id, String fieldOne, String fieldTwo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fieldOne = fieldOne;
        this.fieldTwo = fieldTwo;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "field_one")
    private String fieldOne;

    @Column(name = "field_two")
    private String fieldTwo;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFieldOne() {
        return fieldOne;
    }

    public void setFieldOne(String fieldOne) {
        this.fieldOne = fieldOne;
    }

    public String getFieldTwo() {
        return fieldTwo;
    }

    public void setFieldTwo(String fieldTwo) {
        this.fieldTwo = fieldTwo;
    }
}
```

When i try to get this data by the EntityManager firts of all I have receive the EntityManager:

```
EntityManager em = jpaConnectionProvider.getEntityManager();
```

Then I try to get the data from my custom table:

```
StoreTestModel storeTestModel = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM store_test_model u WHERE u.fieldOne = :fieldOne", StoreTestModel.class).setParameter("fieldOne", "test one").getSingleResult();
```

my persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="api-extensions">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS</jta-data-source>

        <class>keycloak.apiextension.entity.StoreTestModel</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

but i recive the exception:

`ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-611) Uncaught server error: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: store_test_model is not mapped [SELECT u FROM store_test_model u WHERE u.fieldOne = :fieldOne]`

plese, help me to solve this issue

Comment: You should use class names, not table names, i.e. `SELECT u FROM StoreTestModel ...`

Comment: Your class is missing an `@Entity` annotation. You also do not need a persistence.xml. Check the [developer guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_extensions_jpa) for how to register your class.

Comment: @Guillaume i have tried your version this to solve the problem but this not help me. i think that the entity manager map only the keycloak models and not use my persistance.xml for map a new models.

Comment: @sventorben i have tried your version this to solve the problem but this not help me. i think that the entity manager map only the keycloak models and not use my persistance.xml for map a new models.

Comment: @proton The way it is documented works perfectly fine for me. See my example [here](https://github.com/sventorben/keycloak-session-model-jpa). You will need to add a JpaEntityProvider like [this](https://github.com/sventorben/keycloak-session-model-jpa/blob/main/src/main/java/de/sventorben/keycloak/models/jpa/authSession/JpaEntityProvider.java#L8).

Comment: @sventorben thanks for your answer, but I found this https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts and continue workin by this examples, it's the same that are you provided for me.